# Что быстрее: скопировать файлы или разархивировать?

Tags: linux, tar

Наверное туповатый вопрос, поскольку по логике разархивация должна быть дольше, тем более если есть сжатие. Но всё же, вдруг не всё так просто как кажется.

Что будет быстрее, скопировать папку с файлами в 1гб, или же разархивировать архив с точно такими же файлами без сжатия.

Comment: Раньше так при работе с флешкой делали. Папку с кучей файлов было быстрее заархивировать -> скопировать -> разархивировать, чем просто копировать (:

Comment: Архиваторы бывают разные. Некоторые распаковывают архив во временную папку и потом копируют. Вообще я не понимаю теги, которые вы повесили. :) Что общего между linux и winrar?

Comment: xD Да это я так,))

Comment: Кстати говоря, tar не сжимает файлы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю все дело в I/O записи, что обычно ниже чем чтения

**Тесты**

```
~$ du -sh test/
5.2G    test/
```

Прямое копирование:

```
~$ time cp -R tmp/ test/
real    0m34.953s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m5.110s
```

Сжатие, копирование, распаковка:

```
~$ time { tar cf tmp.tar tmp && mv tmp.tar test/ && tar  xf test/tmp.tar -C test/; }
real    1m1.619s
user    0m0.563s
sys     0m12.964s
```

Копирование уже сжатого каталога:

```
~$ time cp tmp.tar test/
real    0m26.251s
user    0m0.028s
sys     0m4.557s
```

Посчитаем колчиество чтения-записи

Для архива:

```
~$ strace cp tmp.tar test/ 2>&1 | grep -c "read\|write"
55259
~$ strace cp tmp.tar test/ 2>&1 | grep -c "write"
27623
```

Для каталога:

```
~$ strace cp -R tmp test/ 2>&1 | grep -c "read\|write"
70955
~$ strace cp -R tmp test/ 2>&1 | grep -c "write"
32455
```

В итоге разница между количеством записей для каталога и пакета вышла **4832**, что при копирование на медленный носитель, может значительно увеличить время ожидания.

При хорошем CPU имеет смысл паковать все предварительно перед копированием. 
  00

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от скорости диска и процессора. При медленном диске (*c которого* производится чтение) и быстром процессоре может оказаться быстрее разжать из архива, чем скопировать нежатое.